# Start an Activity from a BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, android-service

In my app, I register a `BroadcastReceiver` in the `onCreate()` method of a `Service`.

```
registerReceiver(receiver, newIntentFilter(myAction));
```

Now I need to start an activity from the newly registered `BroadcastReceiver` each time `onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)` happens:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context,MyClass.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(i);
```

The "context" is the `Context` which has been passed to my `BroadcastReceiver`. That successfully worked and started the `Activity`. Is that the correct and reliable way of starting an `Activity` inside a `BraodcastReceiver` from a `Service`? Because there are lots of was for getting the `Context`, like `getApplicationContext()` or`getApplication()`, etc.

**In my situation, is using the `Context` which has been passed to my `BroadcastReceiver` the correct way?**

Comment: `BroadcastReceiver` doesn't have a `Context`.  It's passed a context when `BroadcastReceiver.onReceive()` is called, but it doesn't have one of its own and is not a `Context` through inheritance.

Comment: @Prmths yes, I wanted to say the same thing, sorry If I wasn't clear!

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to start the activity from the service using the "startActivity()" function.

Try something like this:

```
public void startAct() {
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setClass(this, MyActivity.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

and call the function inside your `BroadcastReceiver`.

`android.app.Service` is descendant of `android.app.Context` so you can use the `startActivity` method directly. However since you start this outside any activity you need to set `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag on the intent.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I just want to reach to a reliable way of starting an `Activity` from s `Service`. there is no difference between my code and yours, both use the `Context` of `Service` for filing the `Intent` and `startActivity()` however there are other ways like `getBaseContext()` and so. is our way the correct form?

Comment: I think so, I used it many times before and everything worked and works fine.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is "yes". You can use the `Context` that is passed as a parameter to `onReceive()` to start an activity. You can also use the application's context which you can get like this:

```
context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(i);
```

It makes no difference. Both will work.